# How to convert linq query to lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have problem with converting linq to MVC lambda expression

I have a list of model

```
List<ViewModel> model  = new List<ViewModel>();
```

Here is my Linq query:

```
var myQuery = Model.GroupBy(u => u.MyId)
                   .Select(grp => new
                   {
                       MyId= grp.Key,       
                       Liste = grp.ToList()
                   })
                   .ToList();
```

I want to convert this query to lambda expression. Because it's not easy to pass ViewBag or TempData to view which is without list of model.

```
 model = BusinessLogic.GetAll().GroupBy(k => k.MyId).Select(k => new { MyId=k.Key, Liste=k.ToList()}).ToList();
```

model = BusinessLogic.GetAll() comes like

- MyId = 3, DeptId = 5, UserId=32;
- MyId = 4, DeptId = 5, UserId=15;
- MyId = 5, DeptId = 5, UserId=18;
- MyId = 6, DeptId = 5, UserId=91;

I get "can not be assigned to variable of type" (anonymous) error.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - your code is already using lambda expressions - two of them. We can't really tell much about what's wrong with your final code snippet when we don't know what `BusinessLogic.GetAll()` returns. But you're not creating instance of `ViewModel`..

Comment: I want to equalize "myQuery" to "model". So i can easily pass model to my View.

Comment: Well look at the type of `model` - and then look at what you're creating in the `Select` call. Do you see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a list of anonymous types instead of list of `ViewModel`:

```
 model = BusinessLogic.GetAll()
    .GroupBy(k => k.MyId)
    .Select(k => new ViewModel { MyId=k.Key, Liste=k.ToList()})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I stuck again :( It can't find "Liste". 

I create a List<ViewModel> but i can't group values.

Comment: @Fatih1453 - Thats because your `ViewModel` has no such property. What you are trying to achieve? From the same type `ViewModel` you want the same type as output? but you want to group by `MyId` as well. Please note this will return a list for each group so decide if you want any specific item from that group or you don't need a group by altogether, or else you want to return a different type.

Comment: I solve this problem with using 2 loops and 1 if-else situation.
I usualy stuck at linq. Is there a easy to learn linq book or website to learn queries?